# import networkx -- not importing

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I am on Snow Leopard. I have python 2.6. I installed networkx through "easy_install networkx" then uninstalled and re-installed using the package download from the site.
Each installation doesn't get me anywhere: when I do: "import networkx" I just get an empty response and nothing happens. Any clues?

Comment: As @DavidRobinson says - no news is good news - it's working fine - you don't actually have a problem ;)

Answer (score 2):

If nothing happens, that means it worked. If the installation hadn't worked, there would be an error, along the lines of:

```
>>> import networkx
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named networkx
```

Try the code:

```
G=networkx.Graph()
G.add_edge(1, 2)
print G.nodes()
```

And you should see that it works (prints `[1, 2]`).